# Mixed effects negative binomial with robust standard errors (Huber-white) in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, negative-binomial-distribution, robust-standard-error

I would like to fit a random effects model in R using the negative binomial distribution and reporting robust standard errors.

I was going to try using the sandwich package to compute the robust standard errors from the fitted model object:

```
lmtest::coeftest(my_me_model, vcov = sandwich::vcovHC(my_me_model, type = "HC0"))
```

`lme4::glmer.nb()` allows me to fit a mixed effects model however I am unable to calculate robust standard errors, it looks like the model returned by `lme4::glmer.nb()` is an s4 class.

```
lmtest::coeftest(my_me_model, vcov = sandwich::vcovHC(my_me_model, type = "HC0"))
Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
  no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "c('glmerMod', 'merMod')"
```

[robustlmm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustlmm/vignettes/rlmer.pdf) package function rlmer() allows me to calculate robust standard errors  "huberization of likelihood and DAS-Scale estimation" however I cannot see a way to use the negative binomial with this package.

[ptmixed package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ptmixed/vignettes/Overview_functionalities_ptmixed.html) allows me to fit a mixed effects negative binomial I but cannot see a way to compute robust standard errors. So the reverse issue I encountered with robustlmm.

I also came across [glmTMB package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/index.html) which also allows me to fit a negative bionomial mixed effects model, but where I am also unable to use e.g. sandwich to compute robust standard errors.

How can I fit a mixed effects negative binomial regression and then compute robust standard errors (Huber-white)?

Comment: Your request is exceedingly specialized and I am not sure it has ever been implemented in publicly available software. Standard errors are not very precise and/or meaningful for negative binomial regression at the best of times, even more so for mixed models, and even more so if you want a robust estimate. It there a reason why you think this is (a) a good approach and (b) should be readily available in publicly available software?

Comment: Have Huber-White robust standard errors ever been defined for a non-normal count-based model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandwich covariances are available for a wide range of standard maximum likelihood models in `sandwich` (including the output from `glm()`, `glm.nb()`, `zeroinfl()`, and `hurdle()`). However, for mixed-effects models this is less straightforward but there is the relatively recent work in `merDeriv`:

> Wang T, Merkle EC (2018). "`merDeriv`: Derivative Computations for Linear Mixed
> Effects Models with Application to Robust Standard Errors."
> *Journal of Statistical Software, Code Snippets*, **87**(1), 1–16.
> [doi:10.18637/jss.v087.c01](https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v087.c01).

They include the necessary methods for plugging the output from `lmer()` and `glmer()` into the `sandwich()` function and also provide a `vcov()` method for these objects. However, `vcovHC()` is not applicable but `sandwich()` essentially corresponds to HC0 anyway.

As for objects fitted by `glmer.nb()`: The `vcov()` method in `merDeriv` works for these objects but `sandwich()` does not. I would recommend to get in touch with the `merDeriv` authors and ask them whether it would be possible to support `glmer.nb()` as well.